# How to filter a list based on data that the items holds

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement a search method.
I have a list, let's say:

```dart
List<Users> _users = [user1, user2, user3];
```

My class is:

```dart
class User {
  final String name;
  final String id;
}
```

And the items of the list are:

```dart
var user1 = User(name: "Bob", id: 1);
var user2 = User(name: "Alice", id: 2);
var user3 = User(name: "Joe", id: 3);
```

How can I filter the list based on the user name for example?

Comment: see `Iterable.where` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned, you can use `where()` or there are some other methods. You can [read the doc for more](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.1/dart-core/List-class.html).

Simple demo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<User> _users = [
    User(name: "Bob", id: 1),
    User(name: "Alice", id: 2),
    User(name: "Joe", id: 3),
  ];
  List<User> duplicate = [];
  TextEditingController _textController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _textController = TextEditingController();
    duplicate = _users;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: TextField(
          controller: _textController,
          onChanged: (String value) {
            if (value != "") {
              setState(() {
                _users = _users.where((test) => test.name.toLowerCase().contains(value)).toList(); 
              });
            } else {
              setState(() {
                _users = duplicate; 
              });
            }
          },
        ),//Just to show an demo, you can use flutter search instead this
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: _users.map((user) => Card(child: Text(user.name))).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class User {
  final String name;
  final int id;

  User({this.id, this.name});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `where`

```
List<User> filtered = _users.where((user) => user.name == "Joe" ).toList();
```